# How many Positive Integers divide $72^{100}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, prime-factorization

So I began by finding the prime factorization of $72$, which is: $$ 72 = 2^{3} \times 3^{2}$$ then exponentiating by $100$: $$ 72^{100} = 2^{300} \times 3^{200}$$ and so now the question is asking to count the positive integers (natural numbers) which divide this prime factorization.

So basically is this question asking me to compute the natural numbers which divide $2$ and $3$? wouldn't that just be $1,2$ and $3$? Or am I misinterpreting this (could very well be the case). Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Hint: Other numbers that also divide your number 4, 6, 24.

Comment: Doesn't $2^{42}\times3^{69}$ divide $2^{300}\times3^{200}$?

Comment: I had thought that immediately after I posted it but you guys are damn quick! So can we say for any n,k in the natural numbers (or the integers since $2^{0} \times 2^{0} = 1$ and 1 divides anything) that d = $2^{k} \times 3^{n}$ with k maxing out at 300 and n maxing out at 200?

Comment: So how many *is* that.  There is an exact number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By your analysis, any number of the form $2^i3^j$ with $0 \le i \le 300$ and $0 \le j \le 200$ will divide your number. So, you have $301*201=60501$ possible numbers like that.

Comment: I posted my comment right as you posted your answer.. the timing on this question has been impeccable. Haha! Guess that answers my question on n,k or as you use i,j are in the integers.

Comment: @KyleO'Connell Yeah, you really did all the hard work yourself! :)

Answer (score 0):

Numbers that also divide $2^{300}\cdot 3^{200}$ are things like $2^{50}, 2^{51}, 3^{20},3^{2}, 3^{37},2^{52}\cdot 3^{167},\ldots$ (think about it with $\dfrac{x^{a}}{x^{b}}=x^{a-b}$). So, you need to figure out how many combinations of powers of $2$ and powers of $3$ can be made. There are $301$ such powers of $2$ and $201$ such powers of $3$ giving $201\cdot301=\boxed{60501}$. (If you need to see why I multiplied these bnumbers, try reading a bit here : https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html)